# VS Code Salesforce import picklist value [isActive Tag missing]

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

When importing a picklist, VS Code offers only the Active picklist value, and the tag isActive does not come in the xml import file, how can we make sure we get all active and inactive picklist values

here is what I get and I want to have the tag isActive as well

```
        <value>
            <fullName>Commercial</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
            <label>Commercial</label>
        </value>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you retrieving, a "normal" custom picklist or a global value set? [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customvalue.htm) say

> isActive  boolean
>
> Indicates whether this value is currently active or
> inactive. The default value is true. Users can select only active
> values from a picklist. An API retrieve operation for global picklist
> values returns all active and inactive values in the picklist.
> (Meanwhile, **retrieving the values of a non-global, unrestricted
> picklist returns only the active values**.)